# How can i format formulary with CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button

I have a feedback form, and it happens that in the final phase the same, it is just composed by radios and checkboxes.

It is a goal to me get to align these components, or be to get to leave these radios and these checkboxes, like this:

[image]

I tried besides to consult several posts of the stackoverflow, I tried for me same to do searches and investigations, but without solution to solve the problem.

```html
<div class="row" style="height:50px; width:500px">
  <div class="col-md-3" style="width:840px;">

    <div class="example">
      <div>
        <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" id="shortdistances" value="shortdistances">
        <label for="radio1">Eu não posso andar longas distâncias, no entanto curtas distâncias e escadas não são problema.</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio" id="shortorlongdistances" value="shortorlongdistances" style="vertical-align:inherit">
        <label for="radio2">Eu posso andar longas ou curtas distâncias, mas tenho dificuldades com escadas. Ao mesmo tempo durante o Embarque/Desembarque</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio" value="cannotwalk" style="align-content:left;">
        <label for="radio3">Eu não posso andar</label>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="example">
      <div>
        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="cgvd">
        <label for="checkbox1">Eu sou sego, ou tenho deficiência visual severa</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="srds">
        <label for="checkbox2">Eu sou surdo, ou tenho deficiência auditiva severa</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="example">
      <div>
        <input id="radiobutton1" type="radio" name="radioc" id="needdog" value="shortdistances" style="vertical-align:inherit">
        <label for="radiobutton1"></label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="radiobutton2" type="radio" name="radioc" id="needdogpsicol" value="shortdistances" style="vertical-align:inherit">
        <label for="radiobutton2">Eu preciso viajar na companhia de um cachorro devido a razões psicológicas</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="radiobutton2" type="radio" name="radioc" id="needdogpsicol" value="shortdistances" style="vertical-align:inherit">
        <label for="radiobutton2">Something similar ...</label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Will it be that anybody gets to help me with a concrete example?

Comment: If you trying to align the checkbox with its label then check `vertical-align` css property.

Comment: @vitor you want space between label and radio button?

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/j5hbt7wr/2/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can make them pretend to be table cells. That way, they are nicely alined. Your HTML is not modified in the example below. I just added the CSS.

```css
.example div {
  display: table-row; 
}
/* input and label always nicely next to each other, takes care of wrapping. */
input, label {
  display: table-cell; 
}
/* Any additional space between input and label, if you like. */
label {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

/* Spacing and line between the groups */
.example {
  padding: 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="height:50px; width:500px">
  <div class="col-md-3" style="width:840px;">

    <div class="example">
      <div>
        <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" id="shortdistances" value="shortdistances">
        <label for="radio1">Eu não posso andar longas distâncias, no entanto curtas distâncias e escadas não são problema.</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio" id="shortorlongdistances" value="shortorlongdistances" style="vertical-align:inherit">
        <label for="radio2">Eu posso andar longas ou curtas distâncias, mas tenho dificuldades com escadas. Ao mesmo tempo durante o Embarque/Desembarque</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio" value="cannotwalk" style="align-content:left;">
        <label for="radio3">Eu não posso andar</label>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="example">
      <div>
        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="cgvd">
        <label for="checkbox1">Eu sou sego, ou tenho deficiência visual severa</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="srds">
        <label for="checkbox2">Eu sou surdo, ou tenho deficiência auditiva severa</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="example">
      <div>
        <input id="radiobutton1" type="radio" name="radioc" id="needdog" value="shortdistances" style="vertical-align:inherit">
        <label for="radiobutton1"></label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="radiobutton2" type="radio" name="radioc" id="needdogpsicol" value="shortdistances" style="vertical-align:inherit">
        <label for="radiobutton2">Eu preciso viajar na companhia de um cachorro devido a razões psicológicas</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="radiobutton2" type="radio" name="radioc" id="needdogpsicol" value="shortdistances" style="vertical-align:inherit">
        <label for="radiobutton2">Something similar ...</label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```